# ¿Por qué cambiamos el artículo en palabras con género femenino por motivos de pronunciación, pero no hacemos lo mismo con las palabras en masculino?

Tags: pronunciación, género

Según [¿Por qué no se dice la agua?](https://www.elmundo.com/portal/opinion/columnistas/por_que_no__se_dice_la_agua.php)

> Cuando un sustantivo femenino (agua, águila, manzana…) empieza por A
> tónica, es decir, que el acento, la fuerza al pronunciar, está en esa
> A (tenga o no tenga tilde), se usa un artículo masculino porque decir
> “la águila” o “la agua” suena feo.

Sin embargo, cuando se trata de palabras en género masculino, no hacemos lo mismo. Por ejemplo, es el limo, en donde en la pronunciación juntamos dos "l", y no la limo, para evitar "que suene feo".

¿Por qué cambiamos el artículo en palabras con género femenino  por motivos de pronunciación, pero no hacemos lo mismo con las palabras en masculino?

Comment: Porque ‘el limo’ se pronuncia /elimo/, juntando el artículo al sustantivo. Por otro lado, nunca pegó hacer lo mismo con el femenino. Pero en otros idiomas, como el italiano, sin ningún problema se dice *l'acqua*.

Answer (score 3):

El cambio del artículo definido femenino es, de hecho, un vestigio del español medieval.

El antiguo artículo definido era "ela" (cf. el pronombre *ella*). Antes de los vocablos que empezaban con consonante, la e se elidía, y antes de las palabras que empezaban con vocal, la última vocal del artículo se elidía (cf. Fr. *l'éléction*, la elección, antes *el elección). A lo largo del tiempo, la a del artículo se iba restaurando antes de los vocablos, menos las que empezaban con a tónica.

El artículo definido masculino antiguo "elo" perdió muy tempranamente la o (cf. *un* vs. *una*, *algún* vs. *alguna*), y como la sonante se podía combinar con cualquier letra sin que sonara mal, nunca hubo la necesidad fonológica de su elisión ni la adición de vocal final para evitar la geminación  (pareciera que la geminación de la l, como en "el limo", nunca les parecía "fea" a los hablantes históricamente).

Del DPD, "el":

> Aunque esta forma es idéntica a la del artículo masculino, en realidad se trata, en estos casos, de una variante formal del artículo femenino. El artículo femenino la deriva del demostrativo latino illa, que, en un primer estadio de su evolución, dio ela, forma que, ante consonante, tendía a perder la e inicial: illa > (e)la + consonante > la; por el contrario, ante vocal, incluso ante vocal átona, la forma ela tendía a perder la a final: illa > el(a) + vocal > el; así, de ela agua > el(a) agua > el agua; de ela arena > el(a) arena > el arena o de ela espada > el(a) espada > el espada. Con el tiempo, esta tendencia solo se mantuvo ante sustantivos que comenzaban por /a/ tónica, y así ha llegado a nuestros días.